# Formatting a replacement from dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, formatting

I use a dictionary for formatting a string with:

```
print '%(duration)s' % {'duration':'898'}
```

Everything works as expected. Now I want to make sure the replacement for %(duration) will be filled with zeros on the left so it has 5 digits. Result should look like: ''00898'' It is guaranteed that duration will never has more 5 digits.

How would `'%(duration)s'` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) here. Example -

```
In [46]: "{duration:0>5}".format(duration='898')
Out[46]: '00898'
```

If you want to use a dictionary, you can unpack the dictionary into the arguments for `.format` . Example -

```
In [48]: "{duration:0>5}".format(**{'duration':'898'})
Out[48]: '00898'
```

In this the main part is - `{duration:0>5}` - here the field name is before the `:` , the `0>` after the `:` indicates right justifying by padding `0`s and `5` indicates the amount of spaces to right justify.

You can find more information about [string format syntax here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 3):

Add a field width, with a leading `0`; this will, however, *only* work with numbers:

```
print '%(duration)05d' % {'duration': 898}
```

Note that I changed the value to an integer, and the formatted to `d`.

Your total field width, including the padding, is 5 characters, and the `0` tells the string formatting code to zero-pad shorter numbers.

If conversion to `int` is not an option, switch to the newer [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print '{duration:0>5s}'.format(**{'duration':'898'})
```

The `0>` part tells the method to right-align and use `0` for padding. For details, see the [*Format Specification Mini-Language* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Demo:

```
>>> print '%(duration)05d' % {'duration': 898}
00898
>>> print '{duration:0>5s}'.format(**{'duration':'898'})
00898
```

Comment: Nearly working. 5 digits work. But i have spaces instead of zeroes.

Comment: @EhmKah: yeah, updated, as the `s` formatter doesn't support this. I'll add a `str.format()` alternative.

Comment: in the 'real' problem i do not know the type of the dictionary values. since i read it from csv. solution from kumar works good. sorry. but thanks for fast anaswer

Comment: @EhmKah: but you are still padding with zeros, so you are assuming they are numbers. :-)

Comment: @EhmKah: and I note that Anand's answer is identical to my `str.format()` options.

Comment: strange you are right. same answer. thats why i love python there is mostly one elegant solution which works. upvoted your answer but already accepted the other. life is unfair :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.zfill#str.zfill).

> `str.zfill(width)`
>
> Return the numeric string left filled with zeros in a string of length width.

The code would look like

```
>>> print '%(duration)s' % {'duration':'898'.zfill(5)}
00898
```

Comment: might work, but the 'real' values are loaded from csv file. so i can  not fill each of them to 5 characters. solution from kumar works. thank you for your answer

Comment: @EhmKah You are welcome. But do accept the answer that solves your problem (in this case ASK's). All the best in future.